An unhandled exception occurred: You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMap
Getting below error with below configuration
Output

Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMapConsumer.initialize({ 'lib/mappings.wasm': ... }) before using SourceMapConsumer


Windows 11 Pro
node -v v18.20.5
npm -v  10.9.0
ng --version 18.2.12

Used with below suggested option but same error

$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--no-experimental-fetch"

I do not want downgrade version.
